# Missing Field for Group Products

Tags: attributes, ce-1.7.0.2, product-attribute, grouped-products

If I select "Group Product" to create a group product the Name Field is missing under Product Information --> General. However, if I select "Simple Product" the name field appears. Based on information I could find, the Name field should also appear for Group Product. How do I fix this?

Screen shot below shows the name field missing.

[image: Screen Grab of Group Products add/edit]

Answer (score 3):

Solved this issue by logging into the Magento administration and clicking on Catalog --> Attributes --> Manage Attributes. Edited Name Attribute --> "Apply To" and Selected "Group Products" or you can select "Apply to All Project Type".